# Django custom user field clashes with AbstractBaseUser

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I am building a Django project from an existing database. The database is being used by other systems, so I cannot change its schema. This is my current custom User model:

```
class Users(AbstractBaseUser):
    id_user = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    role = models.IntegerField()
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    last_login_date = models.DateTimeField()
```

AbstractBaseUser needs a column named `last_login`, while current database table has `last_login_date` column which serves like `AbstractBaseUser.last_login`. Now I need to use that column in `Users.last_login`:

```
    ...
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(_('last login'), default=timezone.now, column_name='last_login_date')
    ...
```

However Django would throw `django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Local field 'last_login' in class 'Users' clashes with field of similar name from base class 'AbstractBaseUser'` since Django does not allow overriding parent's fields.

How to set the fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't figure out a good way to do this, so I'll give you two rather unsatisfying (but workable) <s>solutions</s> hacks:

1. Rather than inheriting from AbstractBaseUser, take advantage of Django's open-source-ness and copy their AbstractBaseUser code (it's located at <...>lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py) and use a direct implementation of it with `column_name='last_login_date'` in the last_login field. (the AbstractBaseUser class is also [here](http://pastebin.com/T4LSsfNG) (version 1.7))
2. Edit <...>lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py directly (resulting in non-portable code that will not work on another django installation without hacking it too)

Comment: If no-one else can find a better solution, you might want to submit a bug report with the Django project to see if they can allow  column names to be overridden in their AbstractBaseUser class for purposes of complying with legacy databases.

Comment: Thanks. ATM I use your first suggestion while waiting for another answer.

Answer (score 3):

Although there is an answer that already satisfied the question I want to contribute with another way of achieving the same task in a more robust way.

As you already know, Django AbstractBaseUser is the base class that should be used to substitute Django User Class. Such a class inherits from models.Model with is the one that actually creates the model.

This class takes advantage of the metaclass of the python data model to alter the creation process.

And that's exactly what we should do. As you can read on [Python Data Model](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-class-creation) you can use **metaclass** special attribute to alter the creation process as you could see. In your case you could have done the following:

```
def myoverridenmeta(name, bases, adict):
    newClass = type(name, bases, adict)
    for field in newClass._meta.fields:
        if field.attname == 'last_login':
            field.column = 'last_login_date'
            field.db_column = 'last_login_date'
    return newClass

class Users(AbstractBaseUser):
    id_user = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    role = models.IntegerField()
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)

    __metaclass__ = myoverridenmeta
```